# Is AOF or RDB are required for redis cluster?

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

Redis have 2 persistence options: RDB and AOF. But not sure if it uses them to replicate data from masters to slaves. Should i keep one of them enabled for redis cluster or does it replicate data in some other way?

In documentation i found:

"If you wish, you can disable persistence at all, if you want your data to just exist as long as the server is running."

but not sure if this also true for cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persistence is separate from replication; Redis uses the network for replication.  You can disable persistence and still have replication from masters to slaves.